# Injection on instantiated Scriptable Object from Game Object Context Installer

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I'm stuck on something about Zenject/Extenject. Any one has any idea how I can fix that ?

I have `Player` gameObject with `Game Object Context` which instantiate `Character` prefab by factory and `Charcater` has `Game Object Context`. In `CharacterController` which is a facade class on `Character` I instantiate a few Scriptable Objects in this way:

```cs
private readonly DiContainer _container;

public ZenjectResourceFactory(DiContainer container)
{
    _container = container;
}
public Object Instantiate(Object @object)
{
    Object instance = Object.Instantiate(@object);
    _container.QueueForInject(instance);
    return instance;
}
```

In the `Character` Installer `CharacterBehavior` and `CharacterPowerup` are bound by `Container.Bind<CharacterBehaviorContext>().AsSingle().NonLazy();` and `Container.Bind<CharacterPowerupContext>().AsSingle().NonLazy();`

But the issue is `CharacterBehavior` and `CharacterPowerup` are not injected into those Scriptable Objects `[Inject]` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating these instances after the initial install phase, then I believe using DiContainer.Instantiate instead of Object.Instantiate and QueueForInject would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately it doesn't work either.
Also as I noticed, actually DiContainer.Instantiate is Object.Instantiate + DiContainer.Inject and I think they are totally same things. But again, I've tested that and no success.